# Where can I get passport size face photo database for my image classification experiment?

Tags: image-processing

I am just trying to classify images using kNN algorithm with the aid of MATLAB. So now I am in need of some collection of images of peoples' faces. Where can I get some open database of faces (both females and males).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an up-to-date index of face image databases commonly used by researchers.

http://www.face-rec.org/databases/

It contains links to the common datasets such as The Yale Face Database (regular and "B"), The Color FERET Database, The AT&T Database of Faces, etc.

It should cover your needs.

Comment: good to see a lot of links

Comment: If you found the answer useful I would appreciate it if you marked it as accepted.

Comment: I will mark it useful surely when it turns out useful. Let me go through all databases. And also the most database is available only after request (so to access those takes time) and some are huge in size (8 GB etc). So let me see if I can get a small database (in size) from this link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[Face Database1](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/dtg/attarchive/facedatabase.html) Download link available on 4th paragraph

[Face Database2](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/Imagedbase.htm#face)

Hope this helps .. Download the compressed files and extract it.. If it is helpful, click the tick mark to accept the answer.

Comment: let me see those